# Detail: Key (job_instance_id)=(72) is not present in table "batch_job_instance"

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-batch

**Was solved**

We have 2 schemas in the db: public and umler.

After that, the dba team has generated the spring batch schema to both schemas above.

And the foreign key was set:

```
umler.job_inst_exec_fk (job_instance_id reference to public.batch_job_instance(job_instance_id) ) =)))
```

----------------Problem-------------------

I was using spring batch in springboot,in which I had a postgres datasource for the job. But when I ran the job, I've got the error:

```
Detail: Key (job_instance_id)=(72) is not present in table "batch_job_instance".; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "batch_job_execution" violates foreign key constraint "job_inst_exec_fk"
  Detail: Key (job_instance_id)=(72) is not present in table "batch_job_instance".] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "batch_job_execution" violates foreign key constraint "job_inst_exec_fk"
  Detail: Key (job_instance_id)=(72) is not present in table "batch_job_instance".
```

The step that I can see are:

1. Find the job by name
2. if not existing, will create a new record into job_instance (with id = 72)
3. Inserting new record into the job_execution. At this step we would meet the error.

Answer (score 0):

**Was solved**

We have 2 schemas in the db: public and umler.

After that, the dba team has generated the spring batch schema to both schemas above.

And the foreign key was set:

```
umler.job_inst_exec_fk (job_instance_id reference to public.batch_job_instance(job_instance_id) ) =)))
```